# Route 53 failover to s3 static web hosting not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have a website stage.example.com, I want to add a maintenance page for it,

so I created a bucket with name stage.example.com, added a index document and then give it proper permissions, Now I can access this page using the url stage.example.com.s3.us-east.com.

for next step, I created a `healthCheck` for `stage.example.com` and as my server and website is dead and healthCheck also showing it is unhealthy, so I assume it is working fine.

Next step I changed my original record set's routing policy to fail over, changed TTL to 60s, associated healthCheck and make this record set primary.

I created another record set with same name, make it a alias , chooses my s3 bucket, routing policy fail over and make it secondary record set.
As my website is already down, but I didn't redirected to my maintenance page.

I have spent time to search for this issue, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you close your browser? Browsers tend not to repeat lookups when they already have an answer in-hand.  Have you checked to see what values the DNS lookup is returning, and the associated TTL value?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. that actually works.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is there any permanent solution for this ?
As It did not open in my browser but working fine if I open it in another PC. in other words, it will only work for new users but not for the existing ones.

Comment: That's the problem with using DNS failover, particularly for a maintenance page.  The opposite problem happens, too -- a user opening their browser for the first time while you're down is likely to "stick" to the maintenance page and think you're down longer than you are.  The problem is with default browser behavior, not specific to Route 53, and as such, I'm not aware of any genuine solution when using DNS failover.

Comment: Okay thanks anyways.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Could you post an answer based on your comment?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using CloudFormation template to create Route53 records with failover.

Turns out that I was using entire s3 endpoint name in my template, rather than just its regional part. Let me explain using the template:

app.cmcloudlab1073.info.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

```
    # Primary Alias record to ELB
    MyRecordSet1:
        Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
        Properties: 
            AliasTarget: 
                DNSName: a05e-MyApp-7DUO60R115J5-258585633.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
                EvaluateTargetHealth: true
                HostedZoneId: Z35SXDOTRQ7X7K   
            Failover: PRIMARY
            HealthCheckId: !Ref MyR53HealthCheck
            HostedZoneId: /hostedzone/Z2ETUSKZPW2K8B
            Name: app.example.com # example domain for which record is created
            SetIdentifier: elb-primary
            Type: A

    # Secondary record - a static s3 website            
    MyRecordSet2:
        Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
        Properties: 
            AliasTarget:             
                DNSName: ---> MY-ISSUE-WAS-HERE <---- 
                EvaluateTargetHealth: false
                HostedZoneId: Z3AQBSTGFYJSTF # for region us-east-1                          
            Failover: SECONDARY
            HostedZoneId: /hostedzone/Z2ETUSKZPW2K8B
            Name: app.example.com # same name as for primary
            SetIdentifier: s3-secondary
            Type: A


    MyR53HealthCheck:
        Type: AWS::Route53::HealthCheck
        Properties: 
            HealthCheckConfig:                
                FailureThreshold: 1
                FullyQualifiedDomainName: a05e-MyApp-7DUO60R115J5-258585633.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com                
                MeasureLatency: false
                Port: 80                
                RequestInterval: 10
                ResourcePath: /
                Type: HTTP
```

For the  `DNSName` in `MyRecordSet2` I was using full s3 endpoint dns name for my static website:

```
app.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com # <-- INCORRECT
```

The correct is only the s3 part:

```
s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com # <-- CORRECT
```

As a side note, after the changed, failover worked perfectly. Did not need to restart any browsers.